# ReactJS state changes unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I am working on a user interface in **React**.
I am currently facing an issue which I do not really know how to debug.
Somehow the state of a component changes unexpectedly. There is no code on my part which changes the state variable however.

The mutation happens when pressing a button, but I have literally written no code which modifies this state variable. Is there a way in React to see who/which functions made changes to the state? How would one debug this kind of scenario?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't help you fix code we can't see. :-) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Side note: There is no state variable in the line of code you've quoted, only a prop.

Comment: Check out [React DevTools](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions), it also supports showing what the current state is and when it is updated.

Comment: @Qurben thanks for the hint, I am already using it, however do you know if there is a possiblity to see/track which functions caused the state change? I thought you could only inspect the current state of the components with it.

Comment: @Momo, that is possible but a bit harder to do. In the profiler tab you can start a profiling session, this shows over time which updates are triggered. In settings there is also an option to show what caused an update.

Answer (score 0):

You've referred to a "state variable" in your question, but the only code shown in your question uses props, not state.

Props are controlled by the parent element, which can change them even after the component has been created. Here's an example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("constructor");
    }

    render() {
        console.log("render");
        return <div>{this.props.childprop}</div>;
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 0};
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(({value}) => ({value: value + 1}));
        }, 500);
        this.cleanup = () => {
            clearInterval(handle);
        };
        setTimeout(this.cleanup, 2000);
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.cleanup) {
            this.cleanup();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {value} = this.state;
        return <Example childprop={value} />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how `App`'s code changes the value of the `childProp` in `Example`, after the `Example` component has been created. Doing so makes the component re-render.

So code in an event handler can easily see an updated prop value, if the parent has changed it.

Comment: I am sorry, my code was misleading and confusing so I removed it. I understand the concept of props and state, my question is really about how I would possibly debug an unexpected state change not knowing where this change originated from?

Comment: @Momo - As I said in a comment on the question, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). The state of your component will not change spontaneously. If you're using a class-based component (as your previous code example suggested you are), look for calls to `setState`, which should be the only thing that changes your component's state. If you have something that's breaking...

Comment: ...the primary rule of React state (don't modify state directly), that'll be harder to find. Look at what things you give access to your state to.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, a way to intercept if a `component` is receiving props update is `componentWillReceiveProps()` function (now is called `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`). A way to intercept if a `component` is chaning his state is `componentWillUpdate()` function (now is called `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()`), Try to use these to debug your application (maybe you will see some unexpected behaviour that could help to understad the cause of your problem).

Comment: Unfortunately, [the OP says they're using state, not props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536583/reactjs-state-changes-unexpectedly/63536675?noredirect=1#comment112351787_63536675). I'm not deleting my answer mostly in order to keep the comment visible. :-) The question can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I saw the answer before OP edits and there was a props on button handler so I thought to props and not only component state.